# How to update password in django?

Tags: python, django

I want to edit my user data from template, bellow are my codes.

```
def guru_edit(request, id):
   Guru = get_object_or_404(DataGuru, GuruUser_FK_id=id)
   GuruUser = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
   if request.method == 'POST':
       form_guru = dataguruform(request.POST, instance=Guru)
       form_user = userform(request.POST, instance=GuruUser)
       if form_guru.is_valid() and form_user.is_valid():
           form_guru.save()
           form_user.save()
           return redirect('index_guru')
   else:
       form_guru = dataguruform(instance=Guru)
       form_user = userform(instance=GuruUser)
  return render(request, 'guru/guru_tambah.html', {'form_user': form_user,'form_guru':form_guru})
```

this is my forms.py

```
class userform(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = User
       fields = ('username','email', 'password','is_staff','is_active','is_superuser')
    widgets={
    'password':TextInput(attrs={'type':'password'})
    }
```

But when i was save from template, the password is not encrypted like it used to be, but just plaintext.
How to make it encripted?

Comment: Hard to say since you dont explain where the password comes into all of this. But im guessing you set the *field* password instead of using the function `set_password`

Comment: `user = form_user.save()` then `user.set_password(password)` and `user.save()`

Comment: post your `userform`

Comment: i have add my userform @itzmeontv

Answer (score 22):

Do not set the password via a form field. Set the password with `User.set_password()` method which accepts your unencrypted password:

```
user_form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=user)
if user_form.is_valid():
    user = user_form.save()
    user.set_password('unencrypted_password')  # replace with your real password
    user.save()
    return redirect('index_guru')
```

I have named the variables and forms in a bit more Django-ish way here, as you can see.

**Background**: The password in Django is stored as a (most commonly PBKDF2) hash in your database. `set_password` takes care of seeking the correct hashing method and salting and hashing your passwords correctly.

Forms should merely contain something like `password` and `password_check` fields that are used to check if your user inputs his or her password correctly. They should not be used to save a *plain* password into your database, which I suspect is happening here by default.

You can use `set_password` inside your forms as well by overriding the `UserForm.save()` method.

Take the time to read through this document:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/passwords/

Comment: Why we don't allow change it from form? if using this method, i must change my views

Comment: As I said you can override the normal `UserForm.save()` method to set the password in the form when you save it, if you want to. You can also check the password validity in `UserForm.clean()` with e.g. the `validate_password` function in Django. If you went with strict MVC ideology you would handle the passwords in the form.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a view using Django's built in forms and views:

In your `views.py`:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.views import PasswordChangeView
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordChangeForm

class UpdatePassword(PasswordChangeView):
    form_class = PasswordChangeForm
    success_url = '/user/edit-profile'
    template_name = 'app/change-password.html'
```

Inside your `urls.py`:

```py
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
path('/change-password', views.UpdatePassword.as_view(), name="update_password"),
]
```